# Data populating outside HTML tags

Tags: codeigniter, view, output, html-table, tablerow

I have a view that I'm populating with results from my db in a `table`
I'm doing it like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        myHeader
    </tr>

    <?php
        if(isset($records)){
            foreach($records as $row){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo $row->name;
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }   
    ?>
</table>
```

The problem is that it isn't populating my table correctly. It populates everything outside the table.

Output

```
<div class="grid-50">
    MyHeader
    user1user2user3user4
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>        
    </table>
</div>
```

Why isn't it outputting the name of the user in a tr inside the table? And why are there two tbody being produced?

Comment: First make sure that `$row->name` exists and has a value. second, you probably looking at browser's `inspect element`. browsers try to fix your bad-coding. look at the `source code` to see the real markups.

Comment: $row-name exists and has the value, those are the user1user2user3. And what did I code bad? What can I improve?

Comment: As @MrLister mentioned, that was your bad ;)

Comment: Indeed :), such a long time I used a table! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the content in `<td>` elements.

```
<tr>
    <td>myHeader</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
echo "<tr>\n<td>";
echo $row->name;
echo "</td>\n</tr>";
```

Edit: and the browser does rearrange the bad content outside of any `tr` in the DOM, that's right, because it doesn't know what to do with the content otherwise. However, I wouldn't know why there are two `tbody` elements being created. No clue how that could happen.

Comment: Oh my! Such a stupid mistake! This was it, I'll accept in a few mins, can't accept yet

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you :-

myHeader

```
    <?php
        if(isset($records)){
            foreach($records as $row){
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row->name;
                echo "</td></tr>";
            }
        }   
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
foreach($records as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row->name;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```